# Adding and sorting elements in array through user input

Tags: java

My program stops after the first element gets into array. Could you help me? Here's the code:
sorry for that
  i've made some changes now  ArrayQueue is my class where all my methods are implemented
QueueElement is another class that holds the type of element.. 
i think the problem now is at the ArrayQueue class

```
              import java.io.*;
             import java.util.Scanner;
           public class QueueTest
          { private static  Scanner scan =new Scanner(System.in);
               public static void main(String[] args)
                   {
              ArrayQueue queue = new ArrayQueue();
              System.out.println("insert :" +
            " P: to print the array "+
            "S: to sort "+
            "E: to empty"); 
            do
             {
        if (userInput.startsWith("Y")) {
            System.out.println("insert the value of element");
            int vl = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("insert the description");
            String p = scan.next();
            System.out.println("insert true or false");
            boolean vlf = scan.nextBoolean();
            queue.shtoElement(new QueueElement(vl, p, vlf));
        } else if (userInput.startsWith("P")) {
            queue.shfaqArray();//display the array
        } else if (userInput.startsWith("S")) {
            queue.rendit();//sort the array
        } else if (userInput.startsWith("E")) {
            queue.Empty();//empty array
        } 
        System.out.println("Insert:" + " P: to display the array "
                + " S: to sort array "
                + " E: to empty");
        userInput = scan.next();
        } while (!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"));
              }
                 }
```

here is the class ArrayQueue

```
                 public class ArrayQueue implements Queue

                             {
                //build the queue
          QueueElement[] tabela= new QueueElement[MADHESIA];
            QueueElement element= new QueueElement();
          //test if queue is empty
             public boolean isEmpty()
                {

               boolean empty = true;
                 for(int k =0;k<tabela.length;k++)
                      {
                            if(tabela[k] !=null)
                        empty =false;
                   break;
                                }
                            return empty;
                                          }

            public boolean isFull()
                {
                    boolean full=false;
                    for(int k=0;k<tabela.length;k++)
            {
        if(tabela[k]!=null)
            full=true;
        break;
            }
    return full;
        }

    //sort the array
        public void rendit()
           { 
    QueueElement temp=tabela[0];
    for(int i=0;i<tabela.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<tabela.length;j++)
            if(tabela[j]!=null)
            {
            if(tabela[j].compareTo(tabela[i])==1)
            {
                tabela[j]=temp;
                tabela[i]=tabela[j];
                temp=tabela[i];
            }
            else 
                {
                nrElementeve++;
                }
            }
        if(tabela[i].getVlefshmeria()==false)
        {
            hiqElement(i,temp);
             }
            }
               }
    // add element into the array

           public void shtoElement(QueueElement el)
                  {     
                if(isEmpty())
        {
        tabela[0]=el;
        }
    else
         {
            for(int i=0;i<tabela.length;i++) 
               {    
                   if(tabela[i]!= null && (el.compareTo(tabela[i])==0))
                       {
    System.out.println("element can't be added into array cause it exists !");
                        }              
                   {
                       if(isFull())
                       {                        
                            int index=tabela.length;
                            tabela=rritMadhesine(tabela);
                            tabela[index]=el;
                     }  
                 else
                 {
            for(int j=0;j<tabela.length;j++)
        {
        if(tabela[j]==null)
                  tabela[j]=el;
        break;
        }
                        }
               }
         }
               }

             } 
       //find max of array

         public QueueElement gjejMax()
            {
          QueueElement max = tabela[0];
           for (QueueElement element :tabela)
              {
    if(element.getValue() > max.getValue())
        {
        max =element;
        }
    return max;
           }
          return max;
                } 
            //find min of array
            public QueueElement gjejMin()
                  {
                    QueueElement min= tabela[0];
                     for(QueueElement element : tabela)
                  {
                  if(element.getValue()< min.getValue())
               {
                    min=element;
                           }
                        return min;
                              }
                              return min;
                                }

             //remove element from array

             public void hiqElement(int indeksi, QueueElement temp) 
                   {
                      if(tabela.length > 0)
                      {
                  if(gjejMax().compareTo(temp)==0 || gjejMin().compareTo(temp)==0)
               {
                   System.out.println("element can't be removed!");
                   }
                     else
            {
                  for(int i=indeksi;i<tabela.length;i++)
                        {
                      tabela[i]=tabela[i+1];
                               }
                    }
                          nrElementeve--;
                                 }
                          }

        //empty array

           public void Empty()
                {
            tabela= new QueueElement[MADHESIA];
                           }

                       //display the array

                  public  void shfaqArray()
                     {
              for(int i=0;i< tabela.length;i++)
               {
              if(tabela[i]!=null)
             {
                System.out.println(tabela[i]);
            }
                else
      break;
                  }
                }

         //increase the length of array

         public static QueueElement [] rritMadhesine(QueueElement[] array){  
            QueueElement[] tab=new QueueElement[array.length+2];  
              return tab; 
                    }
                     private int nrElementeve;
                 private static final int MADHESIA = 10;
                      }
```

Comment: More `?`s means more answers, right.. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Atleast format it properly , a large no of errors also occur since you can miss out the {} in badly formatted code.

Comment: And whats the long commented part in the code ? Remove it if not needed before posting here.

Comment: and what's `ArrayQueue`, its uncompilable code

Comment: Is `ArrayQueue` a custom class? If so the error might be there. It would also help if there were some comments in the code or the strings were in English so that we can better understand what you're trying to do there.

Comment: please provide SSCCE(Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)

Comment: first please provide running code...

Answer (score 2):

Don't know what `ArrayQueue` and `QueueElement` are, but...

It seems like you're reading user input then going through a decision tree to decide what to do based on that input. But at each point, you are re-reading the user input:

```
     if(scan.next().startsWith("Y"))
     {
        System.out.println("Jepni vleren e elem");
        vl=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Jepni pershkrimin  e elem");
        p=scan.next();
        System.out.println("Jepni vlefshmerine e elem");
        vlf=scan.nextBoolean();
        queue.shtoElement(new QueueElement(vl,p,vlf));
     }
     else
     {
        if(scan.next().startsWith("P"))
           queue.shfaqArray();
     }
     if(scan.next().startsWith("E"))
        queue.Empty();
     if(scan.next().startsWith("S"))
        queue.rendit();
     else
     {
        break;
     }
```

I think you want something more like:

```
     String userInput = scan.next();
     if(userInput.startsWith("Y"))
     {
        System.out.println("Jepni vleren e elem");
        vl=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Jepni pershkrimin  e elem");
        p=scan.next();
        System.out.println("Jepni vlefshmerine e elem");
        vlf=scan.nextBoolean();
        queue.shtoElement(new QueueElement(vl,p,vlf));
     }
     else if(userInput.startsWith("P"))
        queue.shfaqArray();
     else if(userInput.startsWith("E"))
        queue.Empty();
     else if(userInput.startsWith("S"))
        queue.rendit();
     else
     {
        break;
     }
```

Where you read the user input once (`String userInput = scan.next();`) and then decide what to do based on the `userInput` variable and not re-scan each time. Also, it looks like you might be missing a couple of `else` statements somewhere in the middle there.

Comment: the problem with my code is that only the first element gets in array, than the prog do nothing,,, i want the prog to continue running until the user input 'q'  , so i want to display " put the value of elem, put the descript of elem.. and if it is true or false"  and these input gets in the array

Comment: @AnnckyHome probably because it either breaks out of the loop or it's waiting for more input because *you are calling `scan.next()` at every if statement*, did you read my answer?

Comment: yes.. i read.. so i don't have to put every time .next() method ??? ok i'll try thanx

Comment: still the same.. cause it gets the first elem i put and than the prog terminates??? any other idea????

Comment: @AnnckyHome Not really, I'm looking at the block of your code that I've highlighted above, which I modified, but I see no modifications in the code in your question. Can you modify the code so as to reflect what you've changed when you said *"so i don't have to put every time .next() method ??? ok i'll try thanx"*?

Comment: i've made the changes at the beggining ...i've added the class ArrayQueue, also made the comments in english...

Comment: @AnnckyHome can't get it to compile, missing a `{` after `else`, there's a stray `i`, `switch()` doesn't take Strings, there's also an extra `while ((ch = getNextChar()) != "\n");` at the bottom that does nothing

Comment: now i've made some changes at the "main" class, but still does nothing...i thing the problem is at the "shtoElement" method that adds elements into the array, cause the prog when executes adds only 2 elements, and then it does nothing... I want this prog to add elements in array, prints the array, sorts the elements and empty the array... any idea???  i know i'm not as clear as i should... but if i were , i wouldn't be asking

Comment: @AnnckyHome does not compile... Seriously, I'm not interested in helping you get your code to even compile. It looks like you're close, and I've answered your original question, but I'm not going to debug your code for you.

Comment: it doesn't compile maybe cause i haven't put here all my classes, the problem is at the method that adds the elements into the array , i've just wanted to know if logically that method is fine...i'm new to java, and i find it a bit difficult to use it... anyway thanx for ansnwering to all my doubts

Comment: @AnnckyHome I think you've got it correct, for the most part, maybe make it so you read from Scanner before you check the input, you just need to get it compiling.